# Left Join To Separate Queries From Same View

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, sum, aggregate-functions

I am still new to learning PSQL and was wondering how to LEFT JOIN two separate queries that I am retrieving from the same materialized view.

Here is my first query:

```
select rep_name, Count(enroll_date) new_orders, Sum(invoice_total) contract_total, Avg(invoice_total) avg_contract_total
from recent_billing_mat_view
where
    enroll_date <= current_date
    AND enroll_date > (current_date - '30 days'::interval)
    AND product_type = 'CTF'
    AND pay_type <> 'Credit'
group by rep_name
```

And it returns the following:

```
rep_name   new_orders  contract_total avg_contract_total
"Alyssa"    9               2515       279.444444444444
"Carlos"    24              6585       274.375
"Cheryle"   14              4871       347.928571428571
"Nicholas"  19              4775       251.315789473684
"Piero"     13              4405.5     338.884615384615
"Susan"     15              4450.5     296.7
"Valerie"   16              4640       290
"Yelitza"   12              3607       300.583333333333
```

Here is my second query:

```
select rep_name,  Count(enroll_date) orders_paid
from recent_billing_mat_view
where
    enroll_date <= current_date
    AND enroll_date > (current_date - '30 days'::interval)
    AND product_type = 'CTF'
    AND pay_type <> 'Credit'
    AND amount_paid > 0
group by rep_name
```

And it returns the following:

```
rep_name    orders_paid
"Alyssa"        6
"Carlos"        16
"Cheryle"       8
"Nicholas"      14
"Piero"         9
"Susan"         8
"Valerie"       10
"Yelitza"       9
```

I am using the 2nd query to get a count of all orders that have paid for each rep and I want to join that on the first query. I am currently getting the error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "LEFT".

Here is what I am working with:

```
select r.rep_name, Count(enroll_date) new_orders, Sum(invoice_total) contract_total, Avg(invoice_total) avg_contract_total
from recent_billing_mat_view r
where
    r.enroll_date <= current_date
    AND r.enroll_date > (current_date - '30 days'::interval)
    AND r.product_type = 'CTF'
    AND r.pay_type <> 'Credit'
group by r.rep_name
LEFT JOIN (
select Count(enroll_date) orders_paid
from recent_billing_mat_view p
where
    p.enroll_date <= current_date
    AND p.enroll_date > (current_date - '30 days'::interval)
    AND p.product_type = 'CTF'
    AND p.pay_type <> 'Credit'
    AND p.amount_paid > 0
group by rep_name
) as p On r.rep_name = p.rep_name
```

What I would like the results to look like:

```
rep_name   new_orders  contract_total avg_contract_total  orders_paid
"Alyssa"    9               2515       279.444444444444        6
"Carlos"    24              6585       274.375                 16
"Cheryle"   14              4871       347.928571428571        8
"Nicholas"  19              4775       251.315789473684        14
"Piero"     13              4405.5     338.884615384615        9
"Susan"     15              4450.5     296.7                   8
"Valerie"   16              4640       290                     10
"Yelitza"   12              3607       300.583333333333        9
```

What am I missing here? Is there a better way to do this without the LEFT JOIN?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second query is quite identical to the first one, excepted for one condition in the `where` clause. You can just use conditional aggregation:

```
select rep_name, 
    count(*) new_orders, 
    sum(invoice_total) contract_total, 
    avg(invoice_total) avg_contract_total,
    count(*) filter(where amount_paid > 0) orders_paid
from recent_billing_mat_view
where
    enroll_date <= current_date
    and enroll_date > current_date - '30 days'::interval
    and product_type = 'CTF'
    and pay_type <> 'Credit'
group by rep_name
```

Note: the way your query is built, `enroll_date` can never be `null` (because it is filterd in the `where` clause): so `count(enroll_date)` is equivalent to `count(*)`, and more efficient as well.